# Make n dimensional diagonal tensor in Julia

Tags: matrix, initialization, julia, tensor, diagonal

For example, let's denote the `ijk`'th element of a 3d tensor by `a[i][j][k]`. Lets say the 3d tensor has same size in each dimension. Then I want to fill `a[i][i][i]` by `constant[i]` for `i` from 1 to `n`. I want all other elements to be 0. Is making a for loop my only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a comprehension:

```
a = [i==j==k ? constant[i] : 0.0 for i=1:n, j=1:n, k=1:n]
```

Comment: Cool!  Almost said list comprehension, but that would be Python.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` already exists (e.g. by `a = zeros(n, n, n)`), you can use the following function to index the main diagonal, which should work for any dimension (and also for non-symmetric cases):

```
diagind(A::AbstractArray{T,N} where T) where N = CartesianIndex.(fill(1:minimum(size(A)), N)...)
```

Then you can simply broadcast:

```
a[diagind(a)] .= constant
```

In case the input can always be assumed to be diagonal, `minimum(size(A))` could of course be replaced by just `N`.